# How do I force IE 7 to render my web page by standards mode?

Tags: internet-explorer

Interface of my website is always breaked in IE 7, the reason can be IE 7 render my website in Quirks Mode So How do I force IE 7 to render my web page by standards mode?

I appended the  tag but that didn't make any change.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem, there is a comment string before the  tag so IE 7 will render my website in Quirks Mode, another version of IE too.

Everybody can refer to the following link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Answer (score 1):

Is the doctype the very first thing in your page? (no whitespace, etc)

Can you provide a link to the live website?